# ggplot2 can't plot right negative numbers-axis need to be fixed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like this and I can't find a way to plot it with ggplot in a right way, so axis and negative values be in right position.

```
df:
allele subject count
1 Ak24:02 her 6.2076749435666
2 Ak24:02 reth 0
3 Ak24:02 las 14.3529411764706
4 Ak24:02 xan 0
5 Ak02:01 her -0.775193798449603
6 Ak02:01 reth 0
7 Ak02:01 las -0.775193798449603
8 Ak02:01 xan  0
...
```

I tryed this code but I think it's definately wrong.

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x = allele, y = count, fill = subject)) + 
      geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "identity", aes(fill= subject)) +
      geom_text(aes(label= 0),position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
                  vjust = ifelse(df[,3]>=0, -0.5, 1) , size= 3)+
      scale_x_discrete(limits = (unique(df$allele))) +
      #scale_y_continuous(labels = abs)+
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#808080","#C0C0C0","#778899","#A9A9A9"))+
      theme_bw(base_size = 9) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "black") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

The plot i take is this:
[image: plot]

The plot i need is something like this:
[image: plot]

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: That image of data does not look like R's way of printing numbers, so I'm guessing that your `count` is of class `character`. If that's the case, you'll need to fix that first. This will be clearer when you provide usable sample data. (Also, please provide the code used to make the plot.) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks,I've edited my question.

It is of class character but previous dataframe i plotted with ggplot but i dfferent way it was also class of character.

Comment: Your `count` variable needs to be numeric. `df$count = as.numeric(df$count)`. You also probably want to change `label = 0` to `label = round(count, 2)` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you soo so much,I got confused and I forgot it needs to be numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fix `count` so that it is numeric:

   ```r
   str(df)
   # 'data.frame': 8 obs. of  3 variables:
   #  $ allele : chr  "Ak24:02" "Ak24:02" "Ak24:02" "Ak24:02" ...
   #  $ subject: chr  "her" "reth" "las" "xan" ...
   #  $ count  : chr  "6.2076749435666" "0" "14.3529411764706" "0" ...
   df$count <- as.numeric(df$count)
   str(df)
   # 'data.frame': 8 obs. of  3 variables:
   #  $ allele : chr  "Ak24:02" "Ak24:02" "Ak24:02" "Ak24:02" ...
   #  $ subject: chr  "her" "reth" "las" "xan" ...
   #  $ count  : num  6.208 0 14.353 0 -0.775 ...
   ```
2. Change your static `label=0` to `label=round(count, 2)`:

   ```r
   ggplot(df, aes(x = allele, y = count, fill = subject)) + 
         geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "identity", aes(fill= subject)) +
         #                    vvvvvvvvvvvvvv--- change to this
         geom_text(aes(label= round(count,2)),position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
                     vjust = ifelse(df[,3]>=0, -0.5, 1) , size= 3)+
         scale_x_discrete(limits = (unique(df$allele))) +
         #scale_y_continuous(labels = abs)+
         scale_fill_manual(values=c("#808080","#C0C0C0","#778899","#A9A9A9"))+
         theme_bw(base_size = 9) +
         geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "black") +
         theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
   ```

[image: ggplot2 with numeric count and proper labels]

---

Data (with the character `count` column):

```r
df <- structure(list(allele = c("Ak24:02", "Ak24:02", "Ak24:02", "Ak24:02", "Ak02:01", "Ak02:01", "Ak02:01", "Ak02:01"), subject = c("her", "reth", "las", "xan", "her", "reth", "las", "xan"), count = c("6.2076749435666", "0", "14.3529411764706", "0", "-0.775193798449603", "0", "-0.775193798449603", "0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```